# How to track the distance the mouse moved?

Tags: javascript

Heyo,

I'm trying to create a dragable slider in vanilla JS.

For this I'm trying to `transform = 'translateX(' + (mouseMovement) + 'px)';` the amount of pixels the mouse has moved in a `carouselSlide.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);` event.

However, I don't know how to store a value of the the first time the mouse moved, + or - current position. So far I tried.

```
//Hover listeners
carouselSlide.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
carouselSlide.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
carouselSlide.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);

function dragStart(){
    var x = event.clientX;
    dragOver(x);
}

function dragEnd(){
    console.log('end');            
}

var lastX = 0;

function dragOver(x){          

    var currentX = event.clientX - x;

    var mouseMove = currentX - lastX;

    
    
    //Slide Direction
    if (currentX > lastX){
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (mouseMove) + 'px)';        
    } else if (currentX < lastX) {
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (mouseMove) + 'px)';
    }

    lastX = currentX;
    
}
```

However, this does not really work. I did find my solutions in another post: [Calculate the distance the mouse is moved during mouse button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573499/calculate-the-distance-the-mouse-is-moved-during-mouse-button-is-pressed)

However, this is jQuery

Comment: You probably don't want to track the movement since the last `dragover` event, but rather the movement since the last `dragstart` event.

Comment: That `x` parameter to the `dragOver` function won't work when the function is called as an event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to bind it so when you start the event store the variable. I would then bind the other events an listen for the change in position. On end, I would remove the events.

```js
function dragStart(evt) {
  const startX = evt.clientX;

  const handleDrag = function(evt) {
    document.querySelector("#out").textContent = evt.clientX - startX;
  }

  const dragEnd = function(evt) {
    this.removeEventListener("drag", handleDrag);
    this.removeEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
  }

  this.addEventListener("drag", handleDrag);
  this.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);

}

var elem = document.querySelector("#test");
elem.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#test div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div draggable="true">X</div>
</div>

<div id="out"></div>
```